# How to use Entity Framework 6 LINQ query for Dynamic tables with same structure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I have a database with multiple tables dynamically added to it. Those tables will always be having same column structure regardless of TableName.

Currently I am using below code for fetching results;

```
var _list = await db.Database
                    .SqlQuery<List<SampleTable_1>>("SELECT * FROM " + table)
                    .ToListAsync();
```

Can I use LINQ or Lambdas for this instead of SQL queries?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, since you don't have types declared.
Meanwhile you may want to have a look at `System.Linq.Dynamic`

https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/